# Query everything that starts with @

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-search

Hi currently I am using twitter search in Twitter4J and was wondering if there is any way I can query for getting tweets that starts with "User Mentions" or more logically @ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) doesn't contain anything which lets you search by *where* a character is in a tweet.

If you have a specific user in mind, you can find all the Tweets which have been sent to them (not just mentioning them) use the `to:` operator.

For example

https://twitter.com/search?q=to%3Aedent&src=typd